# Spring Boot and Proguard

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, proguard, liquibase

I have a simple Spring Boot 1.5.3 application that I am trying to obfuscate with Proguard 5.x using `proguard-maven-plugin`. I have the following `proguard.conf`.

```
-injars ../$FINAL_NAME$/WEB-INF/lib/$FINAL_NAME$.jar

-outjars ./

-optimizations !class/marking/final
-dontoptimize

-adaptresourcefilenames **.properties
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep public class com.test.blah.OnboardingApp {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
-keep public class * extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

-keep class com.test.blah**.dto.** {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier *;
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required *;
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean *;
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary *;
  @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties *;
  @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties *;
  @javax.inject.Inject *;
  @javax.annotation.PostConstruct *;
  @javax.annotation.PreDestroy *;
}

-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Service class *
-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller class *
-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *
-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Repository class *
-keep @org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching class *
-keep @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration class *
-keep @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties class *
-keep @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication class *

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keepparameternames
-keepdirectories com.test.blah
-keepdirectories org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure

-keepclassmembernames class * {
  java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
  java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
  public static ** fromValue(java.lang.String);
}

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembernames public class com.test.blah.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
  static final long serialVersionUID;
  private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
  !static !transient <fields>;
  !private <fields>;
  !private <methods>;
  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
  java.lang.Object writeReplace();
  java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired <fields>;
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired <methods>;
  @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize <methods>;
}
```

Im loading `proguard.conf` with,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/proguarded" />
                    <copy file="proguard.conf" todir="target/proguarded" />
                    <replace file="${project.build.directory}/proguarded/proguard.conf"
                             token="$FINAL_NAME$" value="${project.build.finalName}" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${proguard-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardInclude>${project.build.directory}/proguarded/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have no problems generating the `war` file artifact. However when I deploy to a tomcat instance I get the following error,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.checkChangelogExists(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 42 more
```

In my application I am loading the Liquibase bean with,

```
@Configuration("databaseConfiguration")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.blah.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.test.blah.repository.search")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
        // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
        } else {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest why Im seeing the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick was to use `-keepdirectories` as mentioned in https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#iooptions

If anyone else runs into this, I just added this to the above `proguard.conf` and removed the filters.

So instead of,

```
-keepdirectories com.test.blah
-keepdirectories org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
```

I simply have,

```
-keepdirectories
```

Which seems to cover all directories.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Helped me big time